# vector::push_back(myVec) on to heap. Can you avoid myVec header information on stack?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl, heap-memory

Given the following code snippet:

```
vector<vector<int>> *Vec_2D = new vector<vector<int>>;
vector<int> int_list;       // declaration and header info on stack
Vec_2D.push_back(int_list);

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  (*Vec_2D)[0].push_back(i);  // load some stuff into first array of Vec_2d
}
```

I  declare`int_list` on the stack, and then `push_back`into `Vec_2D` on the heap. Header information for `int_list` is now on stack; I know the elems of `int_list` are on heap. This seems wasteful.

Can this be avoided? Something like:

```
vector<vector<int>> *Vec_2D = new vector<vector<int>>;

Vec_2D.push_back(new vector<int>); // avoid declaration on stack

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  (*Vec_2D)[0].push_back(i);  // load some stuff into first array of Vec_2d
}
```

Is this syntax possible, `vector::push_back(new myVec)`? This way I avoid the decl. on stack, and the header information of the vector on the stack referred to by `int_list`.

Cheers!!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The contents of a vector is dynamically allocated so there really isn't a reason to dynamically allocate the vector itself.

Comment: What did you observe when you tried it yourself?

Comment: Is something like `Vec_2D->push_back(vector<int>());` what you're searching for?

Comment: In this snippet int_list (on the stack) has no elements, therefore no heap allocation.  What's wasteful?  The 20-32 bytes of header information?  You undoubtedly have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: @davidbak that is exactly what i'm talking about. Your right, but this can add up; memory is v.tight for my application.

Comment: @lorro That should do it. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly sure, but is `emplace_back()` what you are looking for?

Comment: As others have pointed out, `push_back` or `emplace_back` are probably what you want.  `push_back` will construct a temporary vector on the stack, `emplace_back` won't.  But `emplace_back` didn't arrive until C++11.  Another option is to simply enclose your stack-allocated vector (int_list) and the push of it inside of curly braces - then it will be temporary and deleted when the block is exited. In that case you could also fill it up directly and then `std::swap` it into a location in the vector-vector you pushed-back or emplaced-back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `emplace_back`:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> *Vec_2D = new vector<vector<int>>;

    Vec_2D->emplace_back(vector<int>{}); // avoid declaration on stack

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        (*Vec_2D)[0].push_back(i);  // load some stuff into first array of Vec_2d
    }

    return 0;
}
```